# How do you write the following code in a regular format without using %>%?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, dplyr

```
# install package for this customized spider chart
devtools::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar", dependencies=TRUE)

library(ggradar)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(scales)   

mtcars %>%
   add_rownames( var = "group" ) %>%
   mutate_each(funs(rescale), -group) %>%
   tail(4) %>% select(1:10) -> mtcars_radar
```

This is code for creating spider/polar chart

```
 ggradar(mtcars_radar) #gives you the following spider chart
```

[image]

Comment: `rescale`?  Is it a customised function or a function in a certain package?

Comment: Well basically, the first argument of each function would be a data frame created in the previous step. For example `df1 <- add_rownames(mtcars, var = "group")`. Hopefully you can see why the `%>%` pipe is more elegant and readable.

Comment: @AdamQuek Yes it's a customized function i believe. please see the edited one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```r
mtcars[] <- lapply(mtcars, scales::rescale)
mtcars$group <- rownames(mtcars)
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL    # not necessary, really
mtcars_radar <- tail(mtcars, 4)[, c(length(mtcars), 1:9)]    # move group to first variable

mtcars_radar
#>             group       mpg cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt
#> 29 Ford Pantera L 0.2297872 1.0 0.6981791 0.7491166 0.6728111 0.4236768
#> 30   Ferrari Dino 0.3957447 0.5 0.1843352 0.4346290 0.3963134 0.3214012
#> 31  Maserati Bora 0.1957447 1.0 0.5734597 1.0000000 0.3594470 0.5259524
#> 32     Volvo 142E 0.4680851 0.0 0.1244699 0.2014134 0.6221198 0.3239581
#>          qsec vs am
#> 29 0.00000000  0  1
#> 30 0.11904762  0  1
#> 31 0.01190476  0  1
#> 32 0.48809524  1  1
```

Comment: when I  tried to run spider1_radar (used your format for another similar dataset) , it shows "Error in tail(spider1, 5)[, c(1:7, length(spider1))] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions". Can you help me with this?

Comment: What does `str(spider1)` look like? Is it a data.frame?

Comment: > str(spider1)
 'table' int [1:5, 1:7] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "" "Balon/Euron Greyjoy" "Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon" "Robb Stark" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "Beyond the Wall" "The Crownlands" "The North" "The Reach" ...  \n   spider1 = table(got$attacking_king, got$region)

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a table (which is a fancy matrix, really), not a data.frame. Try `spider1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(spider1)` first to convert it into a proper data.frame.

Comment: I converted to data frame matrix, still when I try to run ggradar(spider3_radar)..it shows "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables"   spider1 contains all the columns of the newly created data frame matrix and one 'group' column. when spider1_radar was run, one more column called 'group.1' got added to the existing spider1 data frame. Also strangely, the values inside the columns also changed. like '1' became 0.33 and 0.22 etc. Please help

Comment: The documentation for that package is abysmal, but see the most recent edit of the answer above: you need `group` as the first vector in the data.frame, so subset accordingly: `spider1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(spider1); spider1_radar <- tail(spider1, 5)[, c(length(spider1), 1:7)]`

Comment: Got it @alistaire. Thanks a lot for your time. Got the plot, still needs some tuning regarding the size etc. will have to work that out. Also I have a small doubt. the line mtcars[] <- lapply(mtcars, scales::rescale) assigned all the values between 0 and 1 and plot shows between 0 and 100%. How can I change this into just 'count' ?

Comment: That's what `scales::rescale` does. "count" is not clear, but sounds like aggregation. At this point, you're not really asking the same question any more, though. If there's a new coherent question there, ask a new one with suitable sample data to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 1):

`%>%` simply takes the result of the expression/function that comes before it, and passes it as the first argument of the expression/function after it. So the following is equivalent...

```
library(ggradar)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)    

mtcars <- add_rownames(mtcars, var = "group")
mtcars <- mutate_each(mtcars, funs(rescale), -group)
mtcars <- tail(mtcars, 4)
mtcars <- select(mtcars, 1:10)
mtcars_radar <- mtcars

ggradar(mtcars_radar)
```